# Excel table fill color changes to white when changing cell number format

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, format, fill

How do I retain the alternating color fill in an Excel table column while changing the number format of that column?

Comment: Just changing the number format wouldn't alter the background colour of the cell - whether it was in a table or a cell on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use format painter or copy/paste special (format)

Select the range you want to change the number format and use one of the format tools (right click + format cells)